# Delete key is not working

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard, hardware-failure

The <kbd>Delete</kbd> key is not working. I used an external keyboard to check if there is a hardware problem with the keyboard, but it did not help.

Moreover, If I click on any file to open it, it gets deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The way your post is stated, I am assuming you are on a laptop.

The problem is that your delete key is stuck in the pressing position. As a result, you never get a key_down event registered, and because it is already pressed, any file you click is deleted because that is what the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key does.

To solve the problem, first plug out all USB devices, including small dongles and see if the problem goes away or not. If not, press the <kbd>Del</kbd> key a few times such that if it is indeed stuck, you'll get it unstuck. If that doesn't work, reboot while still have all USB devices unplugged. If that doesn't work either, you will have to get your laptop's keyboard replaced.

Comment: How to reboot. My laptop is intel core m3 7th generation.

Comment: Use the trackpad, click on start-> Power icon -> Restart

Comment: It is possible to remove the keycap yourself to clean the button underneath. Worst case you can't put it back on or it feels weird to press. If you break it, you'll have to get a replacement either way. If you REALLY don't want to pay for a replacement or take off the cap: take off the battery and unplug your laptop. Then, pour isopropyl alcohol under the cap. This will not short your laptop or corrode the inside. Let the alcohol dissolve whatever might be causing it to be stuck & let it evaporate (until you can't smell it anymore) and try turning it on. Very jank, could work in a pinch.